# Referencing to output table with specific fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

`Users`. Where `ID` is the primary key

```
++++++++++++++++++
+ID......... Name+
+1 ......... Alex+
+2 ......... Rony+
+3 ......... Fred+
++++++++++++++++++
```

`Order`: Where `Order_id` is the primary key, and `User_Id` is a foreign key

```
Order_Id ............. User_ID ............ Day    
123456   .............    3    ............ Monday
123457   .............    2    ............ Tuesday
123458   .............    1    ............ Friday
```

Now I would like to output the record having an `order_id = 123458`, however, I don't want the output to be :

```
123458   .............    1    ............ Friday
```

I want it to display the name `Alex` instead of value `1`.

I want it like this:

```
Order_id .............    Name    ............ Day
123458   .............    Alex    ............ Friday
```

For example, if I do:

`SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID = 123458` it will display this output:

```
123458   .............    1    ............ Friday
```

As said before, I want the name `Alex` to be displayed instead of value `1`.

Comment: Look up how to do joins in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As d_onimic say is better if you start with a sql tutorial. Here Is a sample of using `INNER JOIN` and creating `as Alias` for the table names

```
SELECT O.OrderID, U.Name, O.Day 
FROM ORDERS as O
INNER JOIN Users as U
  ON O.UserID = U.ID
WHERE ORDER_ID = 123458
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer. If you have time you can optimize it too. I have less time so just posted.

```
select Oders_id, Name, Day
from (select *
      from Users,
           Orders
      where Users.uid = Oders.user_id
        and Oders_id=123458).
```

Comment: why would you use a sub query?